# error while passing data-frame through k-means

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda, cluster-analysis, k-means

Although my data-frame as all the float values everywhere. While passing the data frame through k-means it shows that couldn't convert the string to float.

How to convert nan values if any to float values in the entire data-frame?

Comment: Do you need cluster of each sample as output or cluster centers to be the output? Mention an example in your question.

Comment: Suppose i have a data set with 4 columns and 600 rows in it. Some columns are having integers where as some columns have strings. Ihave read the .csv file having the dataset using pandas. Now i wanted to apply kmeans and want to see the 4 clusters in it generated by k-means.

Comment: mport numpy as np  
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('zipIncome.csv')
print(df)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto').fit(df)
print (kmeans.labels_)
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

Comment: @YoshithaPenaganti I need the cluster samples as output

Comment: use df[col_name]= df[col_name].astype('category');
        df[col_name] = df[col_name].cat.codes; to convert string to categorical variables or one hot encoding and then use your code.

Comment: @YoshithaPenaganti You mean I need to write this before calling kmeans ? If there are 3 columns with Strings so I need to write this 3 times

Comment: Yes!! You have to convert all the three columns if they are strings.

Comment: @YoshithaPenaganti when i am using it thrice it is giving syntax error. df[Month]= df[Month].astype('category')
df[Month] = df[Month].cat.codes
df[District Name]=df[District Name].astype('category')
df[District Name]=df[district_Name].cat.codes
df[Neighborhood Name] = df[Neighborhood Name].astype('category')
df[Neighborhood Name] = df[Neighborhood Name].cat.codes

Comment: Please enter column name as a string. df['Month'] instead of df[Month]

Comment: import numpy as np  
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('unemployment.csv')
print(df)
df[Month]= df[Month].astype('category')
df[Month] = df[Month].cat.codes
df[District Name]=df[District Name].astype('category')
df[District Name]=df[district_Name].cat.codes
df[Neighborhood Name] = df[Neighborhood Name].astype('category')
df[Neighborhood Name] = df[Neighborhood Name].cat.codes

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto').fit(df)
print (kmeans.labels_)

clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(df)
print (clusters)

Comment: Please check spelling mistakes and give column name as df['District Name'] ,df['Month'] and df['Neighborhood Name'] instead of df[District Name] ,df[Month] and df[Neighborhood Name]

Comment: @Yoshitha Penaganti Now the strings are getting converted and processed by k-means. But I am not getting the clusters. Suppose I am having 99 rows in the dataset and I want 3 clusters from k-means . I want to get those 3 clusters in the output

Comment: df['clusters'] = kmeans.labels_ This should give you cluster labels of each sample.

Comment: @Yoshitha Penaganti kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto').fit(df)
df['clusters'] = kmeans.labels_
print(df['clusters']) This is not giving 4 clusters

Comment: @desertnaut please help on this.

Comment: @Yoshitha Penaganti Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do your job and convert all the columns in string format to categorical codes or use one hot encoding of the variables in these columns.

```
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('zipIncome.csv')
print(df)

df[col_name]= df[col_name].astype('category')
df[col_name] = df[col_name].cat.codes
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto').fit(df)
print (kmeans.labels_)
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Comment: Now the strings are getting converted and processed by k-means. But I am not getting the clusters. Suppose I am having 99 rows in the dataset and I want 3 clusters from k-means . I want to get those 3 clusters in the output.

Comment: Three clusters as in Three cluster centers ?

Comment: i wanted to find cluster from two columns,out of which one column have some NaN values. What to do?
I tried the ` df.fillna(0) `,but when i try to fit both the columns,it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it would seem that you only instantiated the KMeans but haven't used it.
You'll need input data X that is clean (*i.e.* no strings etc), let's call it `X`

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto')
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
```

now `clusters` has the cluster number for each sample in X.

(alternatively, you can do the `fit(X)` and then later `predict(X)` separately, but ultimately it is the `predict` that will output the cluster labels that you will need)

If you want to later get clusters on data, you should use `kmeans.predict(new_data)` rather than `fit_predict()` so that KMeans uses the learning from X, and applies it to your new_data (or depending on your needs, you might want to retrain it).
Hope this helps.

Finally, you can add another column to your pandas DataFrame by doing:

```
df['cluster'] = clusters
```

where `'cluster'` is a string for your new column name, you can of course call it whatever you want

Comment: It is very unclear. I have already done those. I am asking how can I display the clusters generated by K-means

Comment: visually? if your data is 2D you can use matplotlib for example, and use color to see the clusters. If you can be a little bit more specific, I can try to help out

Comment: Suppose I am having a dataset in the CSV format. I have 300 rows and  5 columns. I have implemented K-means clustering in that dataset and K-means clustering has generated 3 clusters. I want to print those 3 clusters and then gain an inference from that. How to print those clusters, so that I can see which rows falls in those 3 clusters. Ex: it may be that 200 rows come under the 1st cluster and 50 rows comes under the 2nd cluster and rest 50 comes under the 3rd cluster. I want to print those in the consoles. I don't need to plot.

Comment: that should be addressed in the original answer - `clusters` is an array where each i-th element from X has its cluster (1,2,3 etc) in the i-th element of clusters, so `X[i]` belongs to cluster `clusters[i]`. If you read your csv file then X would be a 300 by 5 matrix, and clusters will be a 300 element array (1D). If you want to pring to the console you can use `print(clusters[i])` for a specific element, or if you want to see the index of all elements in cluster 1 for example, you can do `print(np.where(clusters==c)[0])` where c is the cluster you are interested in.

Comment: df = pandas.read_csv('unemployment.csv')
print(df)  This is how I have read the csv using pandas. kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=600, algorithm = 'auto').fit(df)
This is how i have used this for k-means. Can you tell me how to print the clusters generated from K-means in the console.

Comment: I added another line to my answer, see if that's what you need (after you add the column, you can `print(df)` again and see the results (sorry if it took a while to understand what you meant. I hope that this time we got it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189230/discussion-between-tacratis-and-sayan).